# String key not found in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have what appears to be a very strange problem.  I have a HashMap with one entry that has a key of "1".  When I do a get by that key I get nothing back.  I have no multi-threading, though everything is run in a Swing thread and the map is a member.  Please see this screenshot of the debugger:  http://img207.imageshack.us/i/keynotfound.png/

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that you're having a problem with?

Comment: Could you show some code? How are you inserting and retrieving the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not "nothing", this is, most probably, an empty ArrayList, so the key is found correctly.

If you expect this to be something else and want to know why it isn't what you expect, the best place too look is the place where you put this value to the map.